# Multicurl: не срабатывает CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Tags: redirect, curl, php

Смотрел заголовки, Location присутствует, но по нему не проходит, а отдает 302. Я, конечно, прохожу потом по ней, но это занимает много времени. Читал, что проблема возможна из-за `open_basedir`, но у меня вроде все в порядке.

> open_basedir => no value => no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в ограничении ширины канала сервера. После снятия ограничения все прошло.